# How can I pass variables from Python back to C++?

Tags: python, c++, parameter-passing

I have 2 files - a .cpp file and a .py file. I use `system("python something.py");` to run the .py file and it has to get some input. How do I pass the input back to the .cpp file? I don't use the `Python.h` library, I have two separate files.

Comment: c++ source files are not interpreted by some similar program like python. cpp files must be first compiled / linked, then one can execute the result of the compilation. The exact steps would depend on what's your OS and what's your cpp compiler, and how it is installed.

Comment: What's your actual issue / goal here?

Comment: If there isn't much data, pass commandline arguments to python? If there is more data write it to a file and let the python code pick that up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`system()` is a very blunt hammer and doesn't support much in the way of interaction between the parent and the child process.

If you want to pass information from the Python script back to the C++ parent process, I'd suggest having the python script print() to stdout the information you want to send back to C++, and have the C++ program parse the python script's stdout-output.  `system()` won't let you do that, but you can use `popen()` instead, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int, char **)
{
   FILE * fpIn = popen("python something.py", "r");
   if (fpIn)
   {
      char buf[1024];
      while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fpIn))
      {
         printf("The python script printed:  [%s]\n", buf);
     
         // Code to parse out values from the text in (buf) could go here
      }
      pclose(fpIn);  // note:  be sure to call pclose(), *not* fclose()
   }
   else printf("Couldn't run python script!\n");

   return 0;
}
```

If you want to get more elaborate than that, you'd probably need to [embed a Python interpreter into your C++ program](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html) and then you'd be able to call the Python functions directly and get back their return values as Python objects, but that's a fairly major undertaking which I'm guessing you want to avoid.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I was searching for!

Comment: And I wasn't able to use <Python.h> for some reason..maybe I unzipped the wrong folder or maybe a folder extra (the path kept on changing and I had to change the <folder name> in the #include <<folder name>> by removing the folders which I had extracted. Maybe I didn't extract the whole folder so the path changed in every `include<<I had to remove this/something.cpp>>`. I tried extracting the whole folder but still didn't work. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? I've not installed and used any libraries in C++ so I don't know if I'm doing it correctly.